# Understanding the identity theorem for analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you help me understand the identity theorem?

The question is: does it exist an analytic function $f$ such that: $$f(\frac{1}{n})=f(\frac{-1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
or
$$f(\frac{1}{n})=f(\frac{-1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^3}$$

for $D=\{z: |z|<2\}$.
Limited point of our set is in D. But how to prove that function is analytic?

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, take $f(z) = z^2$.

For the second, first focus on the positive values of $n$. Let $g(z) = z^3$. Then $f(z) = g(z)$ for $z=\frac1n$, and the identity theorem forces $f(z) = z^3$ everywhere on $D$, but this contradicts $f(-\frac1n) = \frac1{n^3}$, so there can be no such function.